# Type parameters issue in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am getting an error when I try to execute this function that uses the type parameter to call the data.

```
data Car a b c = Car { company :: a
                 , model :: b
                 , year :: c
                 } deriving (Show)

myCar :: Car -> String
myCar (Car {company = c, model = m, year = y}) = "This " ++ c ++ " was made in " ++ m ++ " " ++ show (y)
```

I am getting this error

```
* Expecting three more arguments to `Car'
  Expected a type, but `Car' has kind `* -> * -> * -> *'
* In the type signature:
    myCar :: Car -> String
```

It works if I use the type parameters like below

```
data Car = Car { company :: String
                 , model :: String
                 , year :: Int
                 } deriving (Show)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I am getting this error" Rightly so, because the code as written makes no sense. "It works if I do not use the type parameters like below" Also perfectly OK, this is absolutely the right thing to do. So what's the problem?

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the problem, it works when I try to use data types but not when I try to use type parameters.

Comment: Again, what's the problem? Do you expect `company` or `model` to be something else than `String`s, and `year` something else than `Int`? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined the type `Car a b c`, not `Car`. What you are trying to use later is just `Car`, which the compiler warns you about with (for you a bit cryptic) message `Expecting three more arguments to 'Car'`. It actually makes no sense to expect `Car` alone to magically work as a type, what would the fields be? It only starts to make sense once you specify what `a`, `b`, and `c` are. So `Car` can be used to construct a type (say `Car String String String`) and thus it is called a *type constructor*. To distinguish between these and to draw an analogy to the value-level constructions, Haskell uses *kinds* much like it uses *types* to group individual values.

`Car` being of kind `* -> * -> * -> *` means that it takes 3 types in order to produce a concrete 4th type.

To use the compiler magic to auto-derive `Show` you need to ensure that the constituents also instantiate `Show`. Without this the compiler cannot be expected to magically come up with a way to convert arbitrary type into string in any reasonable way (as you expect from `show`). You can achieve this using *constraints* but as far as I know you can add those only when using a language extension `GADTs`

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Car a b c where
    Car :: (Show a, Show b, Show c)
        => { company :: a, model :: b, year :: c }
        -> Car a b c
```

but you still cannot use `deriving Show` directly, since that seems to work only when the type `Car a b c` works for any `a`, `b`, `c`, which is not the case here. At least not with `ghc-7.10`. What this does, is that it merely disallows bad choices of `a`, `b`, `c` when constructing some car. One example of a type without a `Show` instance is the function type, and it makes sense to disallow it by requesting `Show a, Show b, Show c`. Unfortunately, you would need to add

```
instance (Show a, Show b, Show c) => Show (Car a b c) where
    show (Car a b c) = "Car " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " " ++ show c
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems. `Car` by itself isn't a type but a type constructor. Also, you need to add a `Show` constraint to the type parameters in order to make `String`s out of them.

Try this:

```
myCar :: (Show c, Show m, Show y) => Car c m y -> String
myCar (Car c m y) = "This " ++ (show c) ++ " was made in " ++ (show m) ++ " " ++ (show y)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the type signature `myCar :: Car -> String`, you have forgotten to add type parameters to the `Car` type. Since you specify the `Car` type to take 3 type parameters in:

```
data Car a b c = ...
```

at every point in which you use this type, you have to give it 3 type arguments; You can think of `Car a b c` as a type-level function for which you must supply 3 types before you get a type of kind `*`. The error you get that says type `Car` is of kind `* -> * -> * -> *` means that the `Car` type is "higher kinded", which is a fancy way of saying that the type needs to be applied, like a function, to 1 or more types before it becomes a type of kind `*` (a type that takes 0 types as arguments). In this case, you need to apply the type constructor to 3 other types before it becomes a type of kind `*`.

So, a step in the right direction would be to change the type signature to be something like:

```
myCar :: Car String String Int -> String
```

This should resolve your issue.